# Require Confirmation when navigating to a new page

Tags: 8

Not sure if I've phrased this perfectly. Many websites have functionality such that if you're typing in a text window on a page and then go to navigate away from that page (close the tab, hit back, etc) it will give you a confirmation box/window to let you know your information won't be saved.

Is there a way to add something like this to drupal? I've lost several posts by accidentally closing the wrong tab.

Comment: Only way to do this would be with Javascript I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: @Kevin Forgive me, as someone relatively new to Drupal, is there a good resource for how to add random functionality/hard code things from the server side but not break the web interface?

Comment: "add random functionality/hard code things from the server side".  Sounds like you want to write a custom module -- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules -- But follow the stackoverflow link Keven provided for an answer to your original question.